# Checking if an C++ Pointer is valid (in Objective-C(++))

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, pointers

I've adapted Matt Gallagher's ["Testing if an arbitrary pointer is a valid object pointer"](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/testing-if-arbitrary-pointer-is-valid.html) in an iOS project which uses Objective-C++. It's working fine with Objective-C objects but it always tells me that my C++-Pointers are invalid regardless of whether it works or not. Sometimes the Code crashes at the pointer. Sometimes the code works fine. But the test-method always tells me the pointer is wrong.

Is here anybody who knows to adapt this code to C++ classes and objects too? I could imagine that the code is only working with Objective-C according to the use of "Class"

Comment: Have you tried using `nullptr` when you checked if the pointer was valid? If you want to check for valid data, then you need to dereference the pointer and this will result in exc_bad_access (segfault) if the pointer itself is not valid. As of now, i do not think there are any way to actually check the data.

Comment: The method is very specific to Apple's implementation of Objective-C, and is unreliable at best. There is no way to do anything similar for C++ and, as the author notes, "never use this in production code".

Comment: @AlexanderW yes we were checking against nullptr, null, nil, 0... but the code sometimes always continues the execution and crashes then with EXC_BAD_ACCESS which can't be catched...
=> molbdnilo we are using this only to write debug logs to get detailed information about the workflow of our internal testers. They often don't report the crashes correctly...

Comment: The article says _"The most serious limitation of this approach is that it can never guarantee anything. For this reason, it is important that you never use this in production code."_ Really, the whole thing is a terrible idea; you _cannot_ check whether a pointer is valid, in C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit really NO other way? There isn't a way to catch the EXC_BAD_ACCESS Signal/Exception too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of a pointer variable is either: A null pointer, a valid pointer to an object, a valid pointer to an array element or past the last element of an array, or some invalid pointer.

If it is an invalid pointer, then *any* attempt to use it invokes undefined behaviour. That includes *any* attempt to check that it is an invalid pointer. And there you are stuck. All you can do is check whether it is a null pointer, or whether it is equal to some other valid pointer.

You should go with the Objective-C philosophy: Trying to use an invalid pointer is a programming error. You don't try to detect and handle this at runtime. You let it crash and fix the bug in your code.

Answer (score 1):

C++ pointers simply reference an address in memory. You could look at what's there in memory using a memory viewer tool, but that wouldn't even guarantee that the memory is still valid. For example:

```
char* test = new[13];

strcpy(test, "Hello World!");
delete[] test;
.
.
.
printf("%s", test);
```

In some cases this will print successfully. Sometimes it will print a garbage string. And sometimes it will segfault. There is nothing there to speak to the pointer's validity.

If you're looking at a program that has just segfaulted and you're trying to see what happened there are a few options available to you:

- You can look at the memory through a memory viewer, that in combination with the line you faulted on can provide insight.
- You can seed your memory before running to make this clearer use `0xbadfood5` or something similar.
- Use Valgrind when running is a great tool, if you can deal with the overhead.

The best option is to do error checking in your code. It sounds like you don't have that or you wouldn't be here. Preconditions and postconditions are great and will save you a ton of time in the long run (like now.) However as a silver lining you should exploit this to exact better coding standards in your organization for the future.